# Parent div height not fits child image height

Tags: html, css

This is probably a very easy question, but I can't figure out how to make parent div element's height the same as the child image height.

[Here is a plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tq37MAWlewWSF8gWwsSj?p=preview)

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/3/3d/Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg/aid2076316-728px-Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you inspect parent div, then you'll find that it's height is bigger than the child image's. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your CSS in your question. See [mcve]

Comment: Display block on the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give the image a style of `display:block` otherwise you will get the gap at the bottom:

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black
}
#parent > img {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img src="http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/3/3d/Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg/aid2076316-728px-Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative 1

Set `display: block` on your `<img>`, like @Pete demonstrates. This is probably the preferred solution.

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black
}
#parent > img {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img src="http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/3/3d/Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg/aid2076316-728px-Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg">
</div>
```

---

#### Alternative 2

Remove white-spacing on your `#parent` by either setting `line-height: 0` or `font-size:0`.

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img src="http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/3/3d/Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg/aid2076316-728px-Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg">
</div>
```

---

#### Alternative 3

Add a negative margin. This is a rather poor solution, but I believe it's worth mentioning.

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#parent > img {
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img src="http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/3/3d/Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg/aid2076316-728px-Become-a-Ghost-Step-5.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the line height solution as the user might want to add text into the parent div. @pete has the best answer.

Comment: @andyjones, indeed, as I point out. However, alternatives are worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Pete said. Add `display:block` to your `#parent > img`. Img is an inline-block element by default.